# Debugging python package containing pyx

Tags: python, debugging, scikit-learn, cython

I want to step through a pyx file contained in a python package (sklearn to be precise). Particularly I want to launch a python script and break when the binary code of a particular line in a certain pyx file is executed. I read some howtos (like http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/debugging.html) but none of them seems to say how to do this. The only one which seems to address my particular problem is [this](http://whoateallthepy.blogspot.com/2012/08/quick-cython-debugging.html) article, but I'd like to have a cleaner solution.

Comment: `when a particular line in a certain pyx file is executed` - The pyx file is never executed. It is translated into c code, then compiled into a binary.

Comment: ops I posted the wrong link, I wanted to post the one you mentioned. I followed that howto but it doesn't address my same problem.

Comment: I think best way to do something in this case - debug with print statements. Add print statemetns into pyx, translate it and compile.